# Link is not working when URL is embedded in an anchor tag

Tags: html

I don't understand why embedding (scraped) URLs to online documents don't work whilst embedded in anchor tags.  It looks fine to me and the URLs work fine when pasted into a browser address bar...

Here is an example:

```
<a href=''https://search.abb.com/library/Download.aspx?DocumentID=5SET0540T1800&LanguageCode=en&DocumentPartId=&Action=Launch''>5SET 0540T1800*  New</a>
```

I have tried embedding the links straight into a webpage and also a WORD document.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `href` attribute like this:

`<a href='https://search.abb.com/library/Download.aspx?DocumentID=5SET0540T1800&LanguageCode=en&DocumentPartId=&Action=Launch'>5SET 0540T1800*  New</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is quotes double time around link -> `''link''`. Change it to `'link'`

```
<a href='https://search.abb.com/library/Download.aspx?DocumentID=5SET0540T1800&LanguageCode=en&DocumentPartId=&Action=Launch'>5SET 0540T1800*  New</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `"` double quotes instead of 2 single quotes.

```
<a href="https://search.abb.com/library/Download.aspx?DocumentID=5SET0540T1800&LanguageCode=en&DocumentPartId=&Action=Launch">5SET 0540T1800*  New</a>
```